# Displaying data (retrieved from a website) in a table with PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I would like to retrieve data from [this site](https://www.agriconomie.com/assortiment-de-pouples-beta-double-spire/p210645) with PHP and display it.

I have retrieved the desired values (from articles the article name, price as well as other values below) in 3 different tables using the `pregmatch` function in PHP. What is still remaining is, to display them in a table with two dimensions.

The table should have the article name and the price in the first line. The rest of the lines should contain the titles followed by their values.

This is my current PHP code:

```
<?php

$debut="https://www.agriconomie.com";
$txt = file_get_contents('https://www.agriconomie.com/pieces-agricoles/tracteur/attelage---relevage/pc2902');    /*ici c'est pour Lire la page html*/

$results = array();
// $test = preg_match_all('#<a href="(.*?)">#', $txt, $names_array);

$test = preg_match_all('#<a href="(.+)" class="(.+)" title="(.+)"#', $txt, $names_array);

/*recupéré les liens du site  en particuliers le text qui se situe entre griffe "" du href*/

for($i = 0; $i < count($names_array[1]); $i++) 
{
    $j=$i;

    $debut="https://www.agriconomie.com".$names_array[1][$i]; 

    $adresse =$debut;
    /* echo $adresse ; ?>    <br /> <?php */

    $page = file_get_contents ($adresse);

    /* preg_match_all ('#<h3 class="product-name">(.+)</h3>#', $page, $names_array5); */                       
    preg_match_all ('#(<dd>(.+)</dd>)#', $page, $names_array2); 
    preg_match_all ('#<span><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>(.*?)</span>#', $page, $names_array3); 
    preg_match_all ('#<p class="price" itemprop="price" content="(.*?)">#', $page, $names_array4);

    echo "<center>";

    echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'>";

    /*
    for($j = 0; $j < count($names_array5[1]); $j++)  
    {
        $NOM   =  $names_array5[1][$j]; 

        echo  'Nom ='.$NOM ; 
    }   
    */ 

    for($j = 0; $j < count($names_array4[1]); $j++)  
    {
        $price   =  $names_array4[1][$j]; 
        echo     'Prix ='.$price.'$' ; 
    } 


    for($i = 0; $i < count($names_array3[1]); $i++) 
    {
        for($j= 0; $j < count($names_array2[1]); $j++){
            $descriptif   =  $names_array2[1][$i];   
        }

        $intitule   =  $names_array3[1][$i]; 
        echo "<tr><td>".$intitule." </td>  <td> ".$descriptif." </td> </tr> ";
    } 
}

echo "</table>";
echo "</center>";

?>
```

Comment: Please format your code before posting your question.

Comment: How can I format my code ? Here is my source code ! Please Help me .

Comment: Your code has been formatted and edited by @Qirel

Comment: Thank ! I hope that some one can Help me .

Comment: You have described what you need to achieve but you didn't tell us what specific issue you encountered when doing your work.

Comment: I can not put them in the 2-dimensional table. As I described in the text above.

Comment: PLEASE HELP ME !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found numerous things to correct/tidy up, so I nearly did a full rewrite.

```
$debut="https://www.agriconomie.com";
$txt = file_get_contents('https://www.agriconomie.com/pieces-agricoles/tracteur/attelage---relevage/pc2902');

if(!preg_match_all('#<a href="([^"]*?)".*?title="([^"]*?)"#',$txt,$desarticles)){exit("Failure @ desarticles");}
foreach($desarticles[1] as $i=>$url_ext){
    $page=file_get_contents("https://www.agriconomie.com{$url_ext}");  // https://www.agriconomie.com/clips-ordinaire-de-9x45-le-cent/p207990

    if(!preg_match_all('#<p class="price" itemprop="price" content="(.*?)">#',$page,$desprix)){exit("Failure @ desprix ($i)");}
    if(!preg_match_all('#<i class="icon-chevron-right"><\/i>(.*?)<\/span>.*?<dd>(.+)<\/dd>#s',$page,$information)){exit("Failure @ information ($i)");}

    echo "<center>";
        echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$desarticles[2][$i]}</td>";  // borrow $i from iteration of $desarticles[1]
                echo "<td>Prix ={$desprix[1][0]}$</td>";  // Price (only one per loop)
            echo "</tr>";
            foreach($information[1] as $k=>$info){
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>{$info}</td>";
                    echo "<td>{$information[2][$k]}</td>";  // borrow $k from iteration of $information[1]
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
    echo "</center>";
}
```

Some of the finer points:

- I sped up regex on $desarticles and omitted the middle capture group.
- I removed some needless variables.
- I replaced iterate/count for loops with foreach loops (to avoid the count condition).
- I merged two preg_match_all lines into one called $information.
- I escaped the closing tags in your regex on $information.
- I created a clean, basic two-column table structure as requested.

Comment: I am much older and wiser now (this answer is from a time when I first started posting answers -- I obviously didn't worry too much about coding standards and best practice back then).  I would no longer recommend parse html with preg_ functions.  A proper DOM parser is the appropriate tool.